# Magento 2.1 Enterprise Edition: CMS hierarchy nodes where page_id is NULL

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento-2.1, cms-pages, magento-enterprise-2

I have noticed an odd issue with Magento 2.1 EE where we end up with hierarchy nodes as part of the Magento EE CMS hierarchy feature which do not relate to any `page_id`, see the attached screenshot below. This seems quite nonsensical to me, as these nodes essentially represent the position of pages in the page hierarchy.

Due to this, I am having some issues on the (custom) front-end which tries to utilize these nodes under the assumption that they all relate to a page. Furthermore, this issue also extends to the Magento 2 hierarchy manager in the back-end, which throws exceptions when trying to insert a page into the hierarchy when (usually unique) `request_url` + `store id` is already taken up by a broken entry.

Now, what I don't get is how these entries exist. We have not modified the node insert logic at all, so I am leaning to say that this is a core bug, but I have no proof at this moment. I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue or if other users of the Enterprise Edition CMS Page Hierarchy may also find similar broken entries via `SELECT * FROM magento_versionscms_hierarchy_node WHERE page_id IS NULL;`.

Any shared experiences and hints are appreciated, if it's indeed a core bug I would want to forward it to the Magento team, but I am kind of missing the exact point in the logic where this issue occurs.

[image: Database query illustrating the problem]